# php reverse array elements

Tags: php, arrays, reverse

I just started learn php and I have some problems when I get somting in array in WordPress. for example

I get array like this `[0,1,2,3,4]`

after get the array I need to reverse it like this `[4,3,2,1,0]`

this my code of array

```
$gallery_images = array_values(get_children('pos_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $gallery->ID));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Always try google and/or the php documentation before posting a question. This question would easily be answered by a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add array_reverse() to reverse your array. This will do the trick for you.

`$gallery_images = array_reverse(array_values(get_children('pos_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent=' . $gallery->ID)));`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to reverse a standard idexed array in php is to use the [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) function.
But if you are just going to loop it out, you might as well use a backwards for-loop:

```
for($i=count($array);$i-->0;) {
  echo $array[$i];
}
```

Which will loop the array in reverse direction.